# How to change email signature via google form with data from google directory

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, google-forms, service-accounts

I am using a Google Apps Script to change the signature of each user with personal data which is accessed via [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference). Therefore I have a Service account with Domain Wide Delegation, which impersonates with an admin account to get all the users and their data and then impersonates which each and every user to change the signature via [GmailAPI](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference).

However now in addition I want to provide a Google Form for each user where the user can add additional information to its signature and set it. The script will need the users information from the Directory but I was wondering if the same approach with impersonating is needed.

With [The Apps Script  advanced Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail) it is possible to set the signature but I did not find a way to access the users data in the Google Directory of the specific user which is sending the form.

If I a service account is needed for that I was wondering where to store the access credentials for that? I don't want is be accessible by every user.

Comment: Have you checked https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/alias_and_signature_settings#managing_signatures

Comment: yes, as I wrote, accessing the signature is not a problem but accessing the user data in the google directory is.

Comment: How exactly do you intend to link the user who fills out the form with a user in your domain?   Im not sure i understand what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to give the users of my domain the ability to change their signature by filling out a form. But the signature also contains user data from the google directory. That is basically it.

Comment: do you mean admin directory?  You service account should have access to that

Comment: sorry, yes I mean admin directory, but then I need to use the service account in the app script right? And I was wondering if there are some securitiy implications when the access keys are stored in the app script of a form where every user has access to it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216281/discussion-between-zlzimon-and-daimto).

Comment: I think the main problem here is that there is no trigger that will fire when a user opens a form to respond, so no way to adapt the form data depending on which user wants to fill the form. Maybe you could deploy a web app an have an HTML form instead of a Google Form?

Comment: No, I can get the active user within google app script but when inside the app script the Google Directory has to be accessed then credentials are needed which are stored in the google app script source code and hence accessible to every user. RIght? This will not happen when I use a web app right?

Comment: Of course you can get the active user and you could give only view-access to the other users (so that they cannot access the script and the credentials), but how are you supposed to populate the Form according to the active user filling it up (and its data from Directory)? There is no trigger for that. This problem wouldn't exist with a web app, though (the HTML form could be populated according to the data coming from Directory, which will depend on the active user), and the user doesn't have to be given access to the script, so wouldn't get access to the credentials. What do you think?